# Не работают стили Orchid Laravel

Tags: laravel, orchid

Я создал проект Laravel согласно инструкциям https://orchid.software/en/docs/quickstart/.

В результате оказалось, что административная панель стилей Orchid не работает. Стили слетевшие. На англоязычном форуме нашел один ответ, что можно запустить команды php artisan orchid:publish и php artisan view:clear

В итоге получилось, что данные были скопированы, но стили так и не восстановились.

Как я могу это исправить?

Текущий путь к файлам стилей и скриптам:

> /vendor/orchid/css/orchid.css?id=3578927bc9308e7a38b3c81d38a8cdad
> /vendor/orchid/js/manifest.js?id=fa18bd350409678078668239241217f5
> /vendor/orchid/js/vendor.js?id=6 27078ee16848736db22766555ad6401
> /vendor/orchid/js/orchid .js?id=b39b4e447cf753dd191ab747020e2d32